# Ionic "await signInWithEmailAndPassword()" not working on iOS simulator/device without livereload

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, capacitor

In my Ionic 5 capacitor app, I have a button that calls this function

```
import {
  signInWithEmailAndPassword, signOut,
  User, UserCredential,
  } from '@angular/fire/auth';
```

//...blah blah blah

```
async signIn(value)
      { 
        try {alert('signing in')
          return (await signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.auth, value.email, value.password)).user
        } catch (error) {
          alert('what the heck?' + error)
        } 
      }
```

This works fine on the web and on Android (it returns the object and proceeds). On iOS simulator & the device, it works with livereload, but without livereload, it does nothing, not even return anything. The 'signing in' pops up, but doesn't proceed from there.

Any idea why this is the case?

Comment: I am facing the exact issue. I don't have an iOS device to test if this is only a simulator issue or if this also happens on physical iOS devices. 

Comment: @SizzlingSquiggle I checked on my iphone, it still cannot call the function

Comment: @Obi did u find the issue? I am struggling since morning :(

Comment: @PuneetKushwah I haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your **app.module.ts** file, add the following to your **imports** array.

```
provideAuth(() => {
      if (Capacitor.isNativePlatform()) {
        return initializeAuth(getApp(), {
          persistence: indexedDBLocalPersistence,
        });
      } else {
        return getAuth();
      }
    }),
```

and import the necessary functions & values from `@angular/fire/auth`.

This is a similar solution to Puneet Kushway. I find this solution better, as it keeps your **app.component.ts** file uncluttered.

Comment: That fixed it. You're a genius! Thanks.

Comment: I was stuck on this issue for months ... thank you very much! Even though in my case, it was an ionic/react project, the same fix applied.

Answer (score 4):

After struggling, luckily I found what needs to be done.

In your **app.component.ts** add below code :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Capacitor } from '@capacitor/core';
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { indexedDBLocalPersistence, initializeAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
    const app = initializeApp(environment.firebase);
    if (Capacitor.isNativePlatform()) {
      initializeAuth(app, {
        persistence: indexedDBLocalPersistence
      });
    }
  }
}
```